# How to receive Ok google action "send mail"?

Tags: android, action, sendmail

My application is handling "android.intent.action.SEND", "android.intent.action.SENDTO" actions, but Ok google "Send mail" action is not showing my app in list, it just displays "Gmail" app, not even yahoo or any other mailing application.

I have tried below code with given intent-filter combination as well but that is also not working.

```
action = "android.intent.action.SEND"  
category ="com.google.android.voicesearch.SELF_NOTE"
```

How I can show my app in the list?